# Unable to connect to Remote Server Using Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am very New to Hadoop  and Hbase. I am trying to create a table from java Code and connect to my remote Server (Hbase)which is (172.80.72.86). Its a linux machine (172.80.72.86). I tried the above

I am getting the following error

```
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.5-1301095, built on 03/15/2012 19:48 GMT
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=user-8329a7141c
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_25
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=D:\workspace\Hbase\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\commons-cli-1.2.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\hbase-dsl-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\commons-lang-2.5.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Downloads\slf4j-1.6.6\slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Downloads\slf4j-1.6.6\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\hbase-0.92.1.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\HAdoop\jars\lib\zookeeper-3.3.5.jar
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Pervasive Stuff\New Training stuff\datarush-6.0.0-26\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\grails-2.0.4\bin;.;
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\DOCUME~1\user\LOCALS~1\Temp\
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Windows XP
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=x86
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=5.1
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=user
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=C:\Documents and Settings\user
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=D:\workspace\Hbase
12/08/22 14:06:49 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
12/08/22 14:06:50 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:06:50 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 3416@user-8329a7141c
12/08/22 14:06:50 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:06:51 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
12/08/22 14:06:51 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 1 times to retry  after sleeping 2000 ms
12/08/22 14:06:52 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:06:53 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:06:53 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
12/08/22 14:06:53 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 2 times to retry  after sleeping 4000 ms
12/08/22 14:06:54 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:06:55 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:06:57 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:06:58 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:06:58 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
12/08/22 14:06:58 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 3 times to retry  after sleeping 8000 ms
12/08/22 14:07:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:01 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:02 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:03 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:05 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:06 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:06 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
12/08/22 14:07:06 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
12/08/22 14:07:06 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode /hbase/master
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
12/08/22 14:07:06 ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
12/08/22 14:07:06 FATAL client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Unexpected exception during initialization, aborting
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
12/08/22 14:07:08 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:09 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:09 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
12/08/22 14:07:09 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 1 times to retry  after sleeping 2000 ms
12/08/22 14:07:10 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:11 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:11 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
12/08/22 14:07:11 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 2 times to retry  after sleeping 4000 ms
12/08/22 14:07:12 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:13 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:15 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:16 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:16 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
12/08/22 14:07:16 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 3 times to retry  after sleeping 8000 ms
12/08/22 14:07:18 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:19 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:20 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:21 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:23 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:24 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:25 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
12/08/22 14:07:26 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143)
12/08/22 14:07:26 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
12/08/22 14:07:26 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
12/08/22 14:07:26 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode /hbase/root-region-server
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
12/08/22 14:07:26 ERROR zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
12/08/22 14:07:26 FATAL client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Unexpected exception during initialization, aborting
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/root-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:583)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@b61fd1 closed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:782)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.finishSetup(HTable.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:171)
    at HBaseConnector.main(HBaseConnector.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the zookeeper IP and proceed. The client Pc has to know where zookeeper is running.

Append the following line , next to the Configuration in your program.

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.80.72.86");  // Your remote Pc where the zookeeper is running. Mention the port if needed."172.80.72.86:60020"
```

Comment: I configured but still its not working, I had username and password to my Hbase-server, I am unable to add username and password in hbase-site.xml file. please give me some suggestions

Comment: In Which OS you have configured Hbase. Have you did SSh.

Comment: Remove this and Restart hbase.    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>60020</value>
    </property>

Comment: Linux machine, my Hadoop is installed, After Removing still the same error

Comment: INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
See this, Your Program is searching the zookeeper in local machine. You are suppose to add this line config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.80.72.86"); even after adding this if it doesn't work. then make sure that zookeeper is active.

Comment: I had a similar error also.  On your windows machine edit your host file and put the IP and name of the linux vm.  Once I did that I was able to talk to hbase on my linux vm via java on my window box...

Comment: could someone clarify where exactly to add this line config.set. The ips are in my host file and the program runs fine when running in debug mode in spring. But once I create a jar file to deploy, the error above occurs.

Comment: I tried adding it to my code Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create(); conf.set("ip","port")

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to load your configuration-file, instead of putting it up manually.

When getting the error "Session 0x0 for server null" one of the likely issues is that your HBase-code doesn't know where to connect. Best way to solve this is to load your hbase-site.xml config-file.

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource(new Path("/XXXX/hbase/hbase-0.98.9/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
```